# Небольшое дополнение к меню на jquery?

Tags: jquery

Всем привет. Есть меню, ознакомиться можете тут http://cash-back.kz/

Так вот там есть выпадающее меню, я хочу сделать что когда меню закрытое то картинка + если открыто то -.

Показываю минимальный код.
HTML

```
    <ul id="menu">
    <li><span>Меню 1</span>
    <ul>
    <li>Выпадающее меню 1</li>
    <li>Выпадающее меню 2</li>
    </ul>

</ul>
```

Jquery

```
$('#menu ul').hide();
 $('#menu li span').click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle('normal');
    if (i==0) {
    Сдесь я показываю +
        i=1;
    } else {
        if (i==1) {
    Сдесб я показываю -
            i=0;
        }
    }
    });
```

Вот весь основной код, поскажите, как реализовать?? в овсновном на php писал, и не очень хорошо знаю jquery. Но такую фичу хочиться.

Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

> Сдесь

**Здесь**

> хочиться.

**Хочется**

```
$('#menu li span').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    var $img = $parent.find('img.state-visualizer'); // ищем само изображение, надо будет подкорректировать под конкретную ситуацию
    var imgSrc = '/images/' + ($parent.data('expanded') ? 'minus' : 'plus') + '.png'; // эта штука посередине называется тернарным оператором. В первый раз из .data() придет undefined, поэтому можно не беспокоиться.
    $this.next().slideToggle('normal');
    $img.attr('src', imgSrc); // ставим тегу изображения новый источник
    $parent.data('expanded', !$parent.data('expanded'); // фиксируем изменение состояния элемента меню на противоположное
});
```

Comment: ого, что то очень сложно, а напримере моего примера нету???
А то тут много не понятного, что такое img.state-visualizer что такое $parent.data('expanded') по проще можно?

Comment: > img.state-visualizer

произвольный селектор

> $parent.data('expanded')

примерно то же самое, что и с классом, только без модификации элементов: jQuery запомнит для элемента $parent свойство expanded и будет его менять при каждом клике. `$element.data(key)` - получить свойство `key`, `$element.data(key, value)` - задать свойству `key` значение `value`.

Answer (score 1):

Ребята спасибо конечно что посоветовали но решается оччень просто. Создаем один класс с кнопка +. Создаем другой класс с кнопкой -. и чере  $(this).toggleClass("click") удаляем и добавляем класс. Все работает чики пуки спасибо.